# How to convert a text string in Google Sheets to date format

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column with dates and time formatted like this in each cell:

Thursday, Jan 21, 2021 4:30 PM-5:00 PM

I want to split this across two columns so that the first column has "DD/MM/YY" and the second has the timeslot.

So it would go from being a cell with:

Thursday, Jan 21, 2021 4:30 PM-5:00 PM

to two cells:

21/01/21  4:30 PM-5:00 PM

What formula can I use in Google Sheets to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Another suggestion (which assumes here that your raw data runs A2:A):

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"^\w+, (.+\d) (\d.+$)","$1~$2"),"~")))`

This will leave your dates in the first column as numeric raw dates rather than as text, so you'd be able to use them in calculations and comparisons later. Just select the first column of the results (i.e., those raw dates, showing as numbers in th 40000 range) and format the entire column (**Format > Number**) in the date format you prefer.

Comment: thank you for your usefull answer, I have a similar issue with a date format that looks like: "January 18, 2021, 5:01:38 PM GMT". Unfortunately I couldn't get the regex right, can you help with this? thnx

Comment: =ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"^(\w+ \d+, \d+), (.+)\D{3}$","$1~$2"),"~"))) [END]

Comment: Happy to help. Would you now take a minute to mark my post as "Best Answer"? This will mark the issue as resolved and allow future site visitors to more easily find the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(TEXT({REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, ", (.+\d{4})")*1, 
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "\d{4} (.+)")}, {"dd/mm/yyyy", "@"})))
```

[image]